# Understanding memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, retain

I try to better understand memory management in Objective C (without ARC).
Currently create simple program to try it in use.

My code

```
...
//create some object
RetainTracker * rt = [RetainTracker new]; //RC=1
NSLog(@"Just created - %lu", (unsigned long)[rt retainCount]);
[rt retain]; // RC=2
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[rt retainCount]);
[rt release]; //RC=1
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[rt retainCount]);
[rt release]; //RC=0 -> call to dealloc    
//call to object rt again after it was deallocated and get RC=1
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[rt retainCount]); //think that here must be exception ?
```

Result :

[image]

So, on result we can see that reference counter still equal to 1 after I release last reference and for object rt.

I go deeper, and investigate with Instruments "life" of this object, got next

[image]

As I understand:

- step 0 - just create - RC=1;
- step 1 - for code `[rt retain]` - RC=2;
- step 3 - for code `[rt release]` - RC=1;
- step 4 - for code `[rt release]` - RC=0;

So, object must be deallocated, but if I call to `[rt retainCount]` after step 4 I got that RC for this object still equal to 1. Why? Maybe I make somewhere mistake or miss something?

Comment: After your 2nd call to `release`, the object is deallocated and `rt` now points to "garbage". Any attempt to use `rt` after the object has been deallocated is undefined. You will get either bad results or a crash.

Comment: I think like you just tell, but I put screenShot - where I get result RC equal to 1 after I call to `dealloc` - thats why I don't understand why it's still have some reference

Comment: Related: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Like I said, once the object is deallocated, `rt` is pointing to garbage memory. Any attempt to use it is bad. Your app could just have easily crashed instead of giving you a confusing result of 1.

Comment: @rmaddy, so you mean that this time it's return 1, in next time it can be crashed? and this just a "bug"?

Comment: You keep missing the point. After the object has been deallocated, any use of `rt` is bad. The pointer is now pointing to junk memory. Your last call to `[rt retainCount]` is NOT being made on the deallocated object. It's being made on garbage memory. The result is meaningless. Never use a pointer to a deallocated object. The results are going to be meaningless or result in a crash.

Comment: @0x7fffffff - thanks for useful link - noted!

Comment: If you "Enable Zombie Objects" in the Diagnostics tab of the scheme settings then your program should crash when the deallocated object is accessed

Comment: @MartinR be honest never hear about "Enable Zombie Objects" - need to read more information about, thanks

Comment: @MartinR - I read about `NSZombieEnabled` -  is a flag that you can enable that will provide a warning when you try to access an object that has been deallocated. Thanks for that, don't know that such thing exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the object is deallocated, using the pointer to the object results in undefined behavior. That is, it can print 1, 42, your program could crash, Hello Kitty could pop up on your computer; anything can happen. Any behavior is consistent with undefined behavior, even behavior that seems to indicate some other thing is happening.

Besides the fact that it's undefined behavior, what you see is very likely based on what you did. After an object is deallocated, its memory is marked as available for use, but the bytes that constituted the object in memory still remain there. So in the immediate time being, it is likely that it hasn't been overwritten with other stuff, and the memory will still "look" like the object that was deallocated, and sending messages to it (though undefined behavior) will likely succeed, because it simply uses the parts of the object that are still in the right place in memory.

As regarding the retain count, you are assuming that when you `release` it, and the retain count (however it is stored in memory) will always be decremented, so that if before the `release` it is 1, afterwards it should be 0. However, they don't have to do this when the retain count is 1, because they know that when you `release` an object with retain count 1, the object will be deallocated, after which you are not supposed to use the object anyway, so they might as well skip decrementing it in this case, because there's no point in updating a variable that won't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are deallocated when the pool is drained when their retain count is 0. The object may still be in memory after you release it. Try accessing it after the next drain and see what happens.

Update:
Yes. My mistake. For some reason I missed the fact that it was not autoreleased. However I was looking into the retainCount method and found this in the documentation: "Do not use this method. (required)".

And follows: "... it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method".

It seems that the retainCount method may not reliably give you the retain count of an object. However, still curious that you can still even send that message to that object which is supposed to have been freed.

Comment: What pool? If you mean an autorelease pool then that doesn't apply here since the object isn't autoreleased.

Comment: as @rmaddy sad - I dont use autorelease - i use `retain/release`. Try with pool - all perfect RC equal to 0, after I call `[pool release]`